# How to make a simple login with Angularjs and MVC as a backend

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to make a simple login page in my angularJS. I have problems in the factory and how to show the data.

So I have a class:

```
public class UsersJsonModel
    {
        public int  Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

And I aaded an API controller to get the data :

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        private IEnumerable<UsersJsonModel> users = new UsersJsonModel[]
            {
                new UsersJsonModel {Id = 1, Username = "Linda", Password = "123456"}
            };

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<UsersJsonModel> Get()
        {
            return users;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public UsersJsonModel Get(string name, string passcode)
        {
            return users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(name) && u.Password.Equals(passcode)).FirstOrDefault(); // string name, string passcode
        }
```

Next step I did is add a state on the app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.datacontext']);
.state('app.login', {
                    url: "/login",
                    views: {
                        'appScreen': {
                            templateUrl: "login.html",
                            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
                        },
                    },
                })
```

And then in the datacontext I have something like this and here is my problem:

```
app.factory('datacontext', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $q, $timeout) {

 var cachedPromises = { users:null };
 var dataservice = {getUsers:getUsers};
      return dataservice; }

        function getUsers(u) {      // I try to do smth here but it does not work 
            return {
                loginUser: function(name, passcode) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var promise = deferred.promise;

                    if (name == 'username' && passcode == 'password') {
                        deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
                    }
                    promise.success = function(fn) {
                        promise.then(fn);
                        return promise;
                    }
                    promise.error = function(fn) {
                        promise.then(null, fn);
                        return promise;
                    }
                    return promise;
                }
            }
        }
       })();
```

And in my controller.js I have the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.datacontext']); 
 app.controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);


    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', 'datacontext'];
    function LoginCtrl($http, $scope, datacontext) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.login = function() {
            getUsers($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
                $state.go('tab.dash');
            }).error(function(data) {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login failed!',
                    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                });
            });
        }
    })
```

In the datacontext, I know I am doing things wrong but I don't know how to fix it. 
I have seen examples online but they work directly with services and I don't know how to apply those codes in my code.

Comment: You just posted lots of code and did not specified where error is ? Do you want us to tell an approach of how to use login in angular and mvc or want to make your code correct ?

Comment: Well I wrote I have a problem at the datacontext part. I wrote something but is not correct and I don't know how to fix it. If you can take a look at the datacontext part, I will really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The code for you login service/factory is a bit perplexing.

As it stands it won't even compile... I'm guessing you might have copied and pasted wrong or something, but here are the relevant issues:

```
app.factory('datacontext', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', 

    //Second parameter is the factory function
    function($http, $q, $timeout) {
      //code for factory function
    }

    //This is simply invalid
    // if it were defined inside your factory
    // function it would work, but as it stands
    // this is just a syntax error
    function getUsers(u) { 
        //code for getUsers
    }

//This is what would normally be the
// closing parenthesis for the '.factory('
// method you are calling, but it looks
// like it's closing out an IIFE instead
// Again, this is just a syntax error
})();
```

Replace your factory `dataService` declaration code with this instead, being sure to fill in the code where I replaced it with comments, and then let us know how things work:

```
app.factory('datacontext', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout',

    function ($http, $q, $timeout) {

        var cachedPromises = {users: null};
        var dataservice = {getUsers: getUsers};

        function getUsers(u) { 
            //code for getUser
        }

        return dataservice;

    }]);
```

Comment: Thannk you I will try it now.